# Jquery Rounded Corner & Div - Remove Gap?

Tags: jquery, html, rounded-corners

Can anyone tell me how to remove the gap that is generated in the middle of the div, from the following code: (paste and name test.html)

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
 <head>
   <script src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
   <script>google.load("jquery", "1.2.6")</script>
   <script src="jquery.corners.js"></script>
 </head>
<body>

<div id="divOuterOuter" style="width: 448px; height: 157px; padding-right:
0px;padding-left: 0px; padding-bottom: 0px; margin: 0px; padding-top: 0px;">

  <div style="width: 448px; height: 120px; background-color:#d1ddf1; padding-right: 
  0px; padding-left: 0px; padding-bottom: 0px; margin: 0px 0px 25px; padding-top: 
  0px;" 
  id="divOuter" class="rounded {20px}"> 
  </div>
</div>

 <script>$(document).ready( function(){
        $('.rounded').corners();
        });</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks in advance!

**Example Of Problem**
[Example Problem http://image2.humyo.com/I/9176883-444407271/M2QyZmIxYThiMDVhM2NlODYwMjM4MDI2MDA0MmI5Y2I=/450/450/0/1238082866.jpg](http://image2.humyo.com/I/9176883-444407271/M2QyZmIxYThiMDVhM2NlODYwMjM4MDI2MDA0MmI5Y2I=/450/450/0/1238082866.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The corners plugin (at least the one I found in http://www.malsup.com/jquery/corner/) is invoked with "corner", not "corners".

Try using this instead:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready( function(){
    $('.rounded').corner();
  });
</script>
```

That's working fine for me in IE 7 and Opera 10.

Comment: As you can see from my photo, the Corners bit is correct as its doing it, the gap is the problem! but cheers anyway Seb.

Comment: PS - I got my origional code from here - Libraries from jQuery.com

Comment: Yeh, sorry, started writing my answer before you posted your image... It's so weird, I really don't know then, sorry :(

Comment: Could you try using the script I linked? Maybe it's a bug in yours and there's no workaround for that...

Comment: Just tried, same result. :( I have wrapped the outside div around the inside div so I can then set a colour to the background of the outer div. Also just found out it renders perfect in Firefox and I believe its todo with the Box Model in IE.

Comment: Tell a lie, it also has the Gap in Chrome & Opera so it looks like FF is the only one displaying correctly :S

Comment: Not sure what your entire code looks like, but it's working for Opera 10 here... Maybe you're using Opera 9?

Answer (score 1):

Remove the 25px bottom margin on the div#divOuter.

Answer (score 0):

Controversial and possibly not helpful answer coming up:

Use:

```
-moz-border-radius      /* for firefox */
-webkit-border-radius   /* for webkit browsers */
```

And ignore Internet Explorer. Rounded corners are a visually nicety and usually not functional elements, so weigh up how much effort you want to put into getting it working for IE users when other, decent browsers make it so easy and reliable.

Comment: jquery.corners.js really is NOT much effort to to get the appearance you want on the majority of browsers in use

Comment: ...assuming you've already got the jQuery library loaded. (which I acknowledge the OP has)

Answer (score 0):

I believe that Tyler has the right answer.  I would just like to add that I develop in FireFox for reasons like this.  Using the [Firebug add-on](http://getfirebug.com/) makes it much easier to trace down CSS problems like this.  You can use "inspect" and select the offending objects and edit the CSS on the fly in FireBug to determine what is causing the gap.